# Accessing Xbox Controller From Mono on ARM Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I'm writing a program in C#/Mono to be run on an ARM computer. It needs to be able to get the state of an Xbox controller plugged in to the system. I have tried a number of various libraries (XInputDotNet, for one), but they have all had various issues (like trying to use incompatible native C++ DLLs).

How can I read the state of an Xbox controller on an ARM machine?

P.S. Although there are similar questions, this is not a duplicate. All the solutions for previous questions fail for one reason or another on ARM.

Comment: This is a pretty big task, and your question as you've written it doesn't show much effort. What other posts are you referring to? What have you tried? What doesn't work? Have you looked into any existing drivers for Xbox controllers that run on Linux? XInputDotNet is an **XInput** wrapper; there is no such thing as DirectX on Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To speak more directly to your task - you need to interface with a USB device. Typically this means opening up a handle to the USB driver, giving you a pipe through which you can read and write data to the USB device. `libusb` is a great way to do that in Linux userspace applications.

Given that you're going to be doing this in C# on mono, you're going to need to do pinvokes to  libusb. If you're not familiar with pinvokes yet, I'd recommend practicing on something small, since they can get complicated very fast; particularly, read about [SafeHandles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle(v=vs.100).ASPX).

There is at least one existing project you could use to base your work off of - [xboxdrv](http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/), which is a userland C++ application, built on top of libusb, that reads and writes the controller's data and presents it as a standard joystick so that any joystick-aware program can utilize it.

Answer (score 0):

The [libusb](http://libusb.info/) library, which can be compiled on any Linux platform, including ARM, actually has a sample program (xusb) that can report the status of an XBox Controller.

See https://github.com/libusb/libusb/blob/master/examples/xusb.c#L945.